# Pandas Vectorized loop and dynamically selecting column label based on cell value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I am using `np.where` to do algorithmic trading backtesting on financial data.
Let's say I have this simple dataframe indexed by date and some of minutes in a day as columns with arbitrary values in cells for feature A and feature B to be used as test conditions.
column_df

```
            300  310  320  330  340  A  B  pred_min1  pred_min2  
2010-04-28    9   10   11   12   13  5  2        330        300   
2010-04-29   19   20   21   22   23  5  2        330        300     
2010-04-30   29   30   31   32   33  1  7        340        330     
2010-04-31   39   40   41   42   43  1  7        340        330
```

I can calculate the return for a day based on specific condition of A and B columns by doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
column_df['return'] = np.where(column_df['A']<column_df['B'],
                      column_df['320']-column_df['310'], 
                      column_df['320']-column_df['300'])
```

which will create a new return column:

```
            300  310  320  330  340  A  B  pred_min1  pred_min2  return
2010-04-28    9   10   11   12   13  5  2        330        300       2
2010-04-29   19   20   21   22   23  5  2        330        300       2
2010-04-30   29   30   31   32   33  1  7        340        330       1
2010-04-31   39   40   41   42   43  1  7        340        330       1
```

Now, if I add two columns of predicted minute at which I want to trade each day, pred_min1 and pred_min2.

How can I test for a certain condition A and B, but dynamically use the column label that I stored in pred_min1 and pred_min2 to calculate the return on that day using the values stored in the columns that these cell values represent for that day?
Essentially, I want a flexible way to select the columns to make the calculation based on the labels found in pred_min1 and pred_min2, element-wise for each row, in a vectorized way without using loops.

I tried:

```
column_df['return'] = np.where(column_df['A']<column_df['B'], 
                      column_df['320']-column_df['310'], 
                      column_df[str(column_df.loc[:,'pred_min1'].values)]-column_df['300'])
```

with error:

```
KeyError: '[330 330 340 340]'
```

I also tried:

```
column_df['return'] = np.where(column_df['A']<column_df['B'], column_df['320']-column_df['310'], column_df[str(column_df.loc[:,'pred_min1'])]-column_df['300'])
```

with error:

```
KeyError: '2019-04-28    330\n2019-04-29    330\n2019-04-30    340\n2019-04-31    340\nName: pred_min1, dtype: int64'
```

and

```
column_df['return'] = np.where(column_df['A']<column_df['B'], column_df['320']-column_df['310'], column_df[str(column_df.pred_min1)]-column_df['300'])
```

with error:

```
KeyError: '2019-04-28    330\n2019-04-29    330\n2019-04-30    340\n2019-04-31    340\nName: pred_min1, dtype: int64'
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: `str(...values)` produces a string `'[1,2,3]'`.  That certainly isn't  a valid index for columns or rows. Why did you use it?

Comment: I used str( ... values) to try to get the values recognized as column labels. That did not work.  Without the string(...values) it gives me this error:    KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([330, 330, 340, 340], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: have you tried `column_df[column_df['pred_min1']]`?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to define a userdefined function in the `apply` method

```
def func(r):
    if r['A'] < r['B']:
        r['return']= r['320']-r['310']
    else:
        r['return'] = r[str(r['pred_min1'])] - r['300']
    return r

df = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: By using the  `apply` method with the parameter `axis=1`, we are "applying" the  function `func` along an axis of the dataframe - in this case axis 1 means row-wise. To use `func(df)`, the function should be defined on a dataframe, which is not the case nor the purpuse.